# How to display upcoming events by dat with Modern Events Calendar Lite

Tags: wp-query, date, events, join-tables

I'm using the plugin [Modern Events Calendar Lite](https://wordpress.org/plugins/modern-events-calendar-lite/).

This is a recent plugin, so actually no doc exist.

So i'm looking a way to display my upcoming events on homepage. But i can not make it to work, because start is stored in a second table.

So i have a wpquery that list custom posts "mec-events", this is ok.
But i'm not able to JOIN info to second table to get start_date & to order posts on its value.

I add you a capture of the second table wp-mec-dates & events are store in wp-mec-events

[image]

Based on this tuto : [Filtering the JOIN tables in WP_Query](https://www.ibenic.com/extending-wp-query-custom-queries-tables/)
exemple code :

```
add_filter( 'posts_join', 'add_other_table', 10, 2 );

/**
 * Joining another table and relating the column post_id with the Post's ID
 *
 * @param string $join String containing joins.
 * @param WP_Query $wp_query Object.
 * @return string
 */
function add_other_table( $join, $wp_query ) {
 global $wpdb;
 $join .= " JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}my_table as mytable on mytable.post_id = {$wpdb->posts}.ID ";
 return $join;
}
```

i figure to do like this :

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type'=> 'mec-events',
        'orderby' => 'dstart',
        'order'    => 'ASC',
    );              

    add_filter( 'posts_join', 'add_other_table', 10, 2 );
    function add_other_table( $join, $upcoming_events_query ) {
        global $wpdb;
        $join .= " JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}mec_dates as wp_mec_dates on wp_mec_dates.post_id = {$wpdb->posts}.ID ";
        return $join;
    }   

    $upcoming_events_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if($upcoming_events_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $upcoming_events_query->have_posts() ) {
            $upcoming_events_query->the_post();

            $image_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url('','liste-etablissements'); 
            $event_cities = get_field('contact_city',$post->ID);
            $start_date = get_field('dstart');
            var_dump($start_date);
?>
    <div class="presta-img-home-events">
        <?php if($image_url[0]) { ?>
            <img src="<?php echo esc_url( $image_url ); ?>" alt="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
        <?php } else { ?>
            <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/placeholder-blog.jpg'; ?>" alt="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
        <?php } ?>
        <div class="presta-img-home-events-overlay"><?php //echo $start_date; ?> - <?php if($event_cities) { $cities = 0; $max_cities = 1; foreach($event_cities as $event_city) { $cities++; if($cities > $max_cities) { break; } echo ''. get_the_title( $event_city->ID ) .''; } } ?></div>
    </div>
    <div class="featured-content-wrapper">
        <h3 class="featured-title"> <a title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
        <!--<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="single_add_to_wishlist" ><?php esc_html_e('Découvrir','BeProvence'); ?><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></a>-->
    </div><!-- featured content wrapper -->
                    <?php
                    }
                }
                    ?>
```

But my var_dump() return "null". So i probably do something wrong.
Any help will be apreciate !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have found a solution, making a custom SQL query

here is the code ( using WPML )

```
        $startday = date("Y-m-d");
        if ( defined( 'ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE' ) ) {
          $lang = ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE;
        }           
        //echo $startday;
        global $wpdb,$post;
        $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_posts, `wp_mec_dates` AS mecd, wp_icl_translations WHERE wp_posts.ID = mecd.post_id and post_status='publish' AND wp_icl_translations.language_code='$lang' AND dstart>'$startday' and  wp_posts.ID = wp_icl_translations.element_id ORDER BY dstart" );
        foreach ($results as $post) {
            setup_postdata($post);
            $event_permalink = get_the_permalink();
            $event_date = $post->dstart; 
            $new_event_date = date("d/m", strtotime($event_date));
            $event_title = get_the_title();
            echo $new_event_date . ' - <a href="'.$event_permalink.'" title="'.$event_title.'">' . substr($event_title,0,38) .'</a><br />';
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array( 
    'posts_per_page' => 5, 
    'post_type' => 'mec-events', 
    'orderby' => 'mec_start_date', 
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'     => 'mec_start_date',
            'value'   => date('Ymd'),
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'DATE'
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).